# Phalcon url encrypt decrypt issue

Tags: encryption, phalcon, crypt

I'm using phalcon 5.2.2. trying to encrypt url but failed to get expected result cause url is encrypting but with error. unable to find what I'm doing wrong?

[Module.php]

```
use Phalcon\Encryption\Crypt;
$di->set('crypt',function() {
    $crypt = new Crypt();
    $crypt->setKey("T4\xb1\x8d\xa9\x98\x05\\\x8c\xbe\x1d\x07&[\x99\x18\xa4~Lc1\xbeW\xb3"); //
    return $crypt;
},true);
```

[Controller]

```
public function productAction($enid = null)
{      
    $id = $this->crypt->decrypt($enid, $this->crypt->getKey());
    $this->view->adata = Products::findFirstByid($id);
}
```

[View]

```
{% for data in adata %}
    <a href="{{url.getBaseUri('')}}index/product/<?php echo($this->crypt->encrypt($data->id)); ?>">{{data.productName}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

[OUTPUT]

[image]